# Pass ref for dispatch in NavigationContainer in react-navigation v5

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Earlier I have been use createAppContainer in my navigation. Now while upgrading to react-navigation v5 i am not able to find a replacement for the dispatch reference passed. Sample code from react navigation given below:

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

class App extends React.Component {
  someEvent() {
    // call navigate for AppNavigator here:
    this.navigator &&
      this.navigator.dispatch(
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: someRouteName })
      );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer
        ref={nav => {
          this.navigator = nav;
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, in version 5, screens are not accessed statically. That means only the sibling/parent/child screens are accessible directly, and for others you **must** specify the hierarchy for the navigator to find and access the nested screen.

This is how it works (also **notice that `routeName` is now `name` and `NavigationActions` is now `CommonActions` and imported from `@react-navigation/native`**) :

```
import {CommonActions} from '@react-navigation/native';

this.navigator.dispatch(
  CommonActions.navigate({name: someRouteName, //immediate screen to start with
                          params:{ screen: **the nested screen name** }
                         })
);
```

You may do this recursively, to gain access to deeper screens as well. For that to happen, just pass this object to the **`dispatch`** function:

```
//object to pass to CommonActions.navigate for dispatch:
{name: screen1Name, 
  params:{screen: screen2Name, 
    params:{screen: screen3Name, 
      params:{screen: screen4Name, 
        params:{screen: screen5Name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to achieve the same goal with **`navigation.navigate`**, just add pass the name of the first screen as the first argument, and the object as the `param`. just like this

```
//2 arguments to pass into navigation.navigate:
(screen1Name, // <--- The first screen is given as a separate argument
  params:{screen: screen2Name, 
    params:{screen: screen3Name, 
      params:{screen: screen4Name, 
        params:{screen: screen5Name
        }
      }
    }
  )
```

---

**Also remember, `AppContainer` is now `NavigationContainer` and is imported from `@react-navigation/native`**